# Why does one Div animate faster than the other

Tags: html, css, animation

Using keyframe animation, the div with an id of "Second" animates slightly before the "first" div starts to. Here is my code shouldn't they move at the same speed by default? any help would be great thanks.

```
body { background-color: black; color: white;}

#First { width: 200px; 
   height: 50px;  
   position: absolute; 
   top:5px; 
   color: black; 
   text-align: center; 
   background-color: yellow; 
   -webkit-transform-origin: top;
   -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
   -webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst
{
0%  {-webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);}
}

#Second { width: 200px; 
      height: 50px;  
      position: absolute; 
      top:5px;  
      left:200px;
      color: black; 
      text-align: center; 
      background-color: green;
      -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
      -webkit-animation: mysecond 1s;
      -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mysecond
{
0%  {-webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);}
}
```

and the HTML,

```
<div id="First">FIRST</div>
<div id="Second">SECOND</div>
```

Code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3p64/

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/x3p64/1/)**</kbd>

`@-webkit-keyframes` were different for both

As per requirements

<kbd>[New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/x3p64/2/)</kbd>

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.2);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.6);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mysecond {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.8);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.6);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.2);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes how is this answer the question?

Comment: There supposed to be different I want it to look like one is pulling the other up when there on top of each other.

Comment: ahh, I get it, let me play around a bit..:)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it is starting before, it just looks like it because of the easing properties.  Both animations are starting and stopping at the same time, they just look different.  Try using a `linear` easing on both.

```
-webkit-animation: mysecond 1s linear;
```